# fetching blob from image uri not working in react native

Tags: react-native, image, blob, uri, imagepicker

When I pass uri to built-in fetch method in react native it gives status code is not provided between the range[200,500]. Following code gets stuck at line-1.

```
line-1 const pictureRes = await fetch(image.uri) -> gives status code 0
line-2 const picture = await pictureRes.blob()
```

Answer (score -1):

A status code of 0 indicates that the fetch request was not completed or failed due to a network error. It can happen for the following reasons:

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Issue: If you are making a request to a different domain or port than your React Native app, the server may block the request due to CORS restrictions. Make sure the server is properly configured to handle cross-origin requests and allows requests from your app's domain or origin.

Network Connectivity Issues: If the device or simulator/emulator running your React Native app does not have an active internet connection, the fetch request will fail, resulting in a status code of 0. Check your network connection.

SSL/HTTPS Errors: If you are making a request to a server with an invalid SSL certificate or over HTTPS, it could cause the request to fail. Ensure that the server's SSL certificate is valid and that it supports HTTPS.

Request Configuration: Double-check your fetch request configuration, such as the URL, request method (GET, POST, etc.), headers, and body. Any incorrect setup can lead to a failed request.

Server-Side Errors: The server you are requesting the image from maybe not functioning correctly, leading to status code 0 responses. Verify the server's status and logs to see if there are any errors.